# jquery datatable date sorting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-plugins, date-format

I am using [datatable plugin](http://www.datatables.net) version 1.8.2 for displaying table on my webpage.

It is working fine except. **It is not sorting dates properly, it is showing "invalid date" in Date object**. below is my code snippet.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

                jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['usdate-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    /*
    a and b are <div> tag with date
    */
                    var texta = ($(a).text()).toString(); // Here I am able to see my date in ' 03-17-2015 12:25:21 AM ' format
                    var textb = ($(b).text()).toString();// Here I am able to see my date in ' 03-17-2015 12:25:21 AM ' format

                    var usDatea = new Date(Date.parse(texta)); // Here it is showing "invalid date"
                    var usDateb = new Date(Date.parse(textb)); 

                    return ((usDatea < usDateb) ? -1 : ((usDatea > usDateb) ?  1 : 0));
                };

                jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['usdate-desc'] = function(a,b) {
 /*
    a and b are <div> tag with date
    */
                    var texta = ($(a).text()).toString(); //same as above
                    var textb = ($(b).text()).toString(); //same as above

                    var usDatea = new Date(Date.parse(texta));  //same as above
                    var usDateb = new Date(Date.parse(textb));  //same as above

                    return ((usDatea < usDateb) ? 1 : ((usDatea > usDateb) ?  -1 : 0));
                };

                $('#tablegridname').dataTable( {
                    "sPaginationType": 'full_numbers',
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "iDisplayLength": 50,
                    "aLengthMenu":[50,100,500,1000],
                    "aaSorting": [[ 4, 'desc' ]],
                    "aoColumns": [null, null, null, null, {"sType": "usdate"}]
                } );

            });
            });
```

Comment: How does the dates look like? It sounds like you are having some dates in a format `Data.parse()` not can recognise. BTW - you should really consider upgading your version of datatables to at least a version 1.9.4.

Comment: Your problem is your date (03-17-2015 12:25:21 AM) is not in an accepted format.  What behavior do you expect when your date is 01-02-2015? January 2nd (American) or February 1st (most of the world)?  Look here and try to get your date in that format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: @davidkonrad I can not do it. because everything is working fine except date sorting and Client won't except it :(

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle it is NOT about Date.parse() method. It is about, I have date in this `03-17-2015 12:25:21 AM ` format and I want to create a date object with this value so that I can compare it. how can I do it? with or without Date.parse()

Comment: It is about Date.parse.  Your date is in a wrong format.  You can't use Date.parse AND that date format.  One must go.

Comment: So I have to manipulate my date after taking it, as a string? (like replace '-' with '/'  etc etc). Is there any straightforward way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/82vh6mp2/

It uses this simple function:

```
    function parseDateForSort(d)
    {
       return d.substring(6,10) + d.substring(0,2) + 
          d.substring(3,5) + d.substring(20) + 
          d.substring(11,19);
    }
```

The function takes advantage of the fact that, luckily, PM comes after AM alphabetically; hence the "d.substring(20)" in the middle of the string.  So we have YYYYMMDD[AM or PM]HH:MM:SS.

In your code you can get rid of Date.parse, and replace your return with:

```
  usDatea = parseDateForSort(texta);
  usDateb = parseDateForSort(textb);

  return ((usDatea < usDateb) ? -1 : ((usDatea > usDateb) ?  1 : 0));
```

Good luck.

**Addendum:**

You can create your own sort type, and then specify the column thusly:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-us-pre": function (v) {
        return parseDateForSort(v);
    },

    "date-us-asc": function ( a, b ) { return a - b; },
    "date-us-desc": function ( a, b ) { return b - a; }
} );
```

And then in your .dataTable call include
`"aoColumnDefs": [ { "sType":"date-us", "aTargets":[6] } ]`

or whatever column number it is instead of 6.